# Black bar down right hand side of IE9

Tags: drivers, internet-explorer-9, graphics, rendering

Slightly weird one this.

Dell Vostro 3550, Windows 7.

IE 9 renders with a black strip down the right hand side. To work the scroll bar, you have to aim the mouse at where the scroll bar SHOULD be, in the black strip.

This is for all websites.

Chrome works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated ATI graphics drivers to latest from Dell website - now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a guide on how to solve this http://www.romcheckfail.com/5/.

To sum it up open internet options and enable GPU Rendering. This fixed the issue for us. We had the latest ATi Drivers.